# javascript date format conversion (full text date to unix time stamp)

Tags: javascript

I have a date in the following format
`Fri Mar 16 2012 05:53:18 GMT 0200 (GTB Standard Time)`

And I want to convert it into a unix timestamp.

Until now I manually split the string by `spaces` and then I am giving it as an input to a `Date` object, in order to get `milliseconds` in a latter step.

Is there any easiest way?
(I am trying to avoid jQuery plug-ins and do it using vanila javascript)

Comment: Seems valid, did you try just passing the string to `new Date`

Comment: @adeneo In my question I have it right, in my code I have it wrong! I was missing the `+` in my actual code. I updated my question to make my mistake clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way would be to pass the string to `Date` object and then call the [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method:

```js
var myDate = new Date('Fri Mar 16 2012 05:53:18 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)');
console.log( myDate.getTime() ); //1331869998000
```

No need to split your string by spaces.

Comment: Thanks! It works! As I pointed in a comment above is was missing the `+` from the `GMT+0200`. That was causing the error.